# Cookie Jar . Queued returns empty - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

Im implementing a custom guard. The attempt method if true queues a token to a "jar"

Im really assuming is the way it works so i would like some feedback if possible.

```
/**
 * Attempts to log-in user into the application
 *
 * @param $credentials
 * @param $rememberToken
 *
 * @return bool
 */

public function attempt($credentials, $rememberToken)
{
    try {
        $response = $this->client->login($credentials);

        Cookie::queue(
            $this->cookieName,
            $response->access_token,
            $response->expires_in
        );

        return true;

    } catch (ClientException $exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code works ok.. But i want to retrieve the queued cookies with the cookieJar in the authenticated method of my custom guard

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param         $user
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $jar = new CookieJar();
    dd($jar->getQueuedCookies()); //returns empty []

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out cookiejar is not a class that should be instantiated the way i was doing it. The solution is to call the static method `Cookie::getQueuedCookies()` to get the array of queued cookies . i'll leave a snippet

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $cookies = Cookie::getQueuedCookies();
    $value   = $cookies[$this->cookieName]->getValue();

    $user = new User();

    $user->name     = "Customer";
    $user->lastname = "1";

    //TODO : $value has an access_token. Call the $this->guard()->setUser()

}
```